# Помогите собрать подобный слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, slider

[image: слайдер]

Помогите собрать подобный слайдер, на js, html и css
можно при помощи библиотеки слик слайдер, но похожий слайдер я там не нашел, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Это обычный слайдер (можно на слике собрать), просто он выходит за пределы контейнера. Задайте контейнеру overflow-x: hidden, а слайдеру какую-нибудь ширину больше контейнера.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант делать подобные слайдеры, которые также называют "каруселями" на библиотеке **Owl Carousel**. В данной библиотеке есть разные варианты каруселей на любой вкус.

Официальный сайт на ГитХабе - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html
Демо разные там же - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html

Можно взять за базу и потом сделать свое, например,

На "слике" можно сделать так - https://codepen.io/sergeiermilov/pen/WNzqWqd

```js
var $st = $('.pagination');
var $slickEl = $('.center');

$slickEl.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
  $st.text(i + ' of ' + slick.slideCount);
});

$slickEl.slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  nextArrow: $(".next"),
  prevArrow :$(".prev"),
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500);

body {
  background: #34495e;
  font-family:Raleway;
}

.container {
  padding: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  text-align: lefr;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*****************************************
*  --------------------------------------*
*  Slick                                 *
*  --------------------------------------*
*****************************************/
.slide {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  transition: ease all 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cl {
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 126px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cl-yellow {
  background: #f1c40f;
}

.cl-blue {
  background: #3498db;
}

.cl-red {
  background: #e74c3c;
}

.slick-active {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.slick-center {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.slick-slide:not(.slick-active) {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
}

.slide:not(.slick-active) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination {
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.slider {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-430px);
  width: 100%;
}
.slick-list {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

button {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick-theme.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Slider</h1>
      <div class="slider center">       
          <div class="slide">
            <div class="cl cl-yellow">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <div class="cl cl-blue">2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <div class="cl cl-red">3</div>
          </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="cl cl-yellow">4</div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <div class="cl cl-blue">5</div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <div class="cl cl-red">6</div>
          </div>
          
      </div>
      <button class="prev">Back</button>
      <button class="next">Next</button>
      <div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
```